# SoundCloud API ERROR return receipt in Russian

Tags: api, codeigniter, lua, soundcloud, helper

When I send a request in English, everything is fine, but when I send a request for songs in Russian, I get errors:

```
local song = "2pac"
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/?q="..song.."&client_id="..KEY.."&limit=200
Result - ok
```

```
local song = "скриптонит"
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/?q="..song.."&client_id="..KEY.."&limit=200
Result - ERROR
```

Comment: convert from win1251 to utf8 before `urlencode`

Answer (score 2):

It works with the api get method you use.

```
local song = urlencode('скриптонит');
```

Comment: Now it doesn’t include songs for some users